# Adding a new contact (Android)

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a new contact using this code:

```
    try{
           ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<android.content.ContentProviderOperation>();

            if(!name.equals("")) {
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
                        .build());
            }

            if(!number.equals("")){
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, number)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                        .build());
            }

            if(!email.equals("")){
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, email)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
                        .build());
            }

            context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I also specified the `WRITE_CONTACTS`permission on the Manifest and I requested it in runtime.

However, although it **does not return any error**, the contact isn't added...

What am I doing bad?

Comment: If your android version is greater than lolipop you need to include run time permissions. Or you can give permissions like this **Settings>Applications>Select your app> see down for permissions> switch the permission***

Comment: Permissions are also granted in runtime...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

It is needed to include this query before trying to store anything:

```
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                    .build());
```